# How to handle events of programatically created tools in a loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, dynamic, datagridview

I am creating a form builder which creates multiple tabs and on each tab will place a DataGridView linked to a dataset in a dataset array:

```
For Each table As DataTable In datasetInput(i).Tables
    If arr_tables(i)(j).Equals(table.TableName) Then
        tablename = table.TableName
        Dim grid As New DataGridView
        grid.DataSource = table
        grid.Name = j
        grid.Location = place
        grid.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(734, 150)
        TabPage.TabPages(i).Controls.Add(grid)
    End If
Next
```

Note that this loop is nested within another loop that handles each tab on the form. arr_tables is a jagged array which handles which tables from the dataset I want because I do not want to pull every datatable into a DGV.

Now what I need to do is format any cell that falls in the column of name "Equation". For all cells in the "Equation" column I want to be a drop down cell with a few different options. Secondly, how can I handle a cell click event? Say any cell that falls in the column name "Input" I want to provide a MessageBox.

Normally I would have no issue doing these things if the DataGridViews weren't created within a loop. But because they are they get lost within the code and I don't know how to reference them.

Thank you!

Comment: They are not lost. You put them in the TabPages' controls collection and that's where you can find them.  You can use `AddHandler to hook up events to the `grid` object variable before you "lose" it.

Comment: Ohhhhh. So I can create the handler within the loop for every grid? Derp don't I feel stupid now. Thanks!!!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if you change a Name to 'grid.Name = "dgw" & j' (names cannot start with numbers, I think), then you should find them where you placed them, with their names, i.e. dgw1, dgw2, dgw3,... in TabPage.Tabpages(i).Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For Each table As DataTable In datasetInput(i).Tables
        If arr_tables(i)(j).Equals(table.TableName) Then
            tablename = table.TableName
            Dim grid As New DataGridView
            grid.DataSource = table
            grid.Name = j
            grid.Location = place
            grid.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(734, 150)
            TabPage.TabPages(i).Controls.Add(grid)

            AddHandler grid.SelectionChanged, AddressOf grid_SelectionChanged

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub grid_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' your code
End Sub
```